# How to block the 2nd field with choices until the choice in the 1st field is selected?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

```
# models.py
class UserSportKinds(AbstractSports):
    KINDS_OF_SPORTS = (
        (1, _('football')),
        (2, _('volleyball')),
        (3, _('hockey')),
    )

    MASTERY_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('newby')),
        (2, _('amateur')),
        (3, _('semi-pro')),
        (4, _('pro'))
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kind_of_sport = models.IntegerField(_('kind of sport'), null=True, blank=True, choices=KINDS_OF_SPORTS)
    mastery = models.IntegerField(_('mastery'), null=True, blank=True, choices=MASTERY_CHOICES)
```

This code allows to have `mastery` without `kind_of_sport`, so admin via admin page and user via its profile may select any `mastery` without corresponding sport. Is it possible to block `mastery` field in template until `kind_of_sport` is selected using django built-in features or any django batteries, so without external\custom javascripts?

Comment: You want to control user experience on the frontend without using JavaScript ?? How is that possible ?

Comment: @karthikr Django uses some js internaly, so in order to avoid handmade work, could be possible that there is a built-in feature that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript that detects the change on first field than enable second field.

with django you cannot achieve that unless it reloads rhe page after select in first field.